# HBase Shell: Readable scan results

Tags: hbase

When I run e.g. a `count' mytable'` in `hbase shell` I get the following results:

```
...
Current count: 264000, row: \x80\x00\x01S\xE1f\xBD\x00\x80\x00\x00\x02\x80\x00&B
Current count: 265000, row: \x80\x00\x01S\xE1\xE5OX\x80\x00\x00\x03\x80\x00\x1E\x04
...
```

Is there a possibility to make this keys (and values on scan) human readable? Or how can I "convert" these keys into the readable format?

I'm writing the data via `DataFrameWriter` to HBase:

```
myDataFrame.write().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("table", TABLE_NAME).option("zkUrl", "zookeeperQuorum:/hbase-unsecure").save();
```

Comment: how you have made this rowkey? is it through java client to insert data in to this table ? if that's the case then you can reverse engineer and decode in the same way.

Comment: I use the DataFrameWriter to save my DF to HBase, added this also to my question. I'd like to select the HBase row via URL, but don't know how to "decode" the row keys like above.

Comment: I think that's why you don't have no control on how rowkey is saved. can you try alternate way to specify rowkey  pattern to the code the insert data with dataframe? Im not sure alternative ways are present or not.. pls. give a try. Currently rowkeys are stored in hex format. you can use meaningful rowkey.